# ASP.NET (6.0) Core MVC Login and Registration using Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0

i have some problems with login/register system, I use identity from .net(I think so), anyway i recive such errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbUux.png).(Error List)
code from errors: 
1:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYwwc.png)(code for creating tables in db)
2:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEtn8.png)(peace of code login.cshtml/register.cshtml)
2.1:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BbTL.png) (Model)
 2.2: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HFni.png) (ExternalLogins)

I don't know if the errors from picture 1 and 2 are connected with errors from login.cshtml / register.cshtml), but these are all the bugs I have.

Comment: Please do not add images of the code(s). Rather put in the actual code to get better responses.

Comment: Yea, you're right :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These messages are not `error` , they are `warning`. you can read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/intellitest-manual/warnings-and-errors?view=vs-2022#maxstack-exceeded) to learn more about `warning and error` in Visual Studio

Comment: Hey, ty for answer i'll check your link.